# Conjugation of Gal$(f)$, considered as a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: galois-theory, symmetric-groups

Given a field $F$ and $f(x) \in F[x]$ a separable polynomial of degree $n$, and denote the roots of $f$ by $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$. We can consider the Galois group Gal$(f)$ as a subgroup, $H$, of $S_n$. Keith Conrad states:

"Two different choices for indexing the roots of f(T) can lead to different subgroups of Sn, but they will be conjugate subgroups"

(Link: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf)

My question is how does one prove the above statement - or in other words; that permutation of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is that same as conjugation of $H$ inside $S_n$?

I know that two groups, say $H$, $T$ (where $T$ is a group in $S_n$  which corresponds to permutation of roots of Gal$(f)$), are conjugate inside $S_n$ iff there exist a $\pi\in S_n$ s.t.:
\begin{equation}
    H=\pi T \pi^{-1}
\end{equation}
But how does one prove that this equality holds?

Comment: What do you think will happen to every automorphism in the Galois group if, instead of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ you decide to call the roots $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_n$ in such a way that $\beta_i=\alpha_{\pi(i)}$ for some permutation $\pi$ of the indices?

Comment: Hm, well I suppose that the structure of the Galois group stays the same. I would even say that considering the permutation you have given, is the same as considering $\sigma(\text{Gal}(f))$ where $\sigma\in \text{Gal}(f)$ and $\sigma(\alpha_i)=\alpha_{\pi(i)}=\beta_i$. I guess then we can call $T$ the corresponding group in $S_n$ to $\sigma(\text{Gal}(f))$.

Comment: Consider the case of $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$. When we label the zeros as $\alpha_1=i$, $\alpha_2=-i$, $\alpha_3=\sqrt2 i$, $\alpha_4=-\sqrt2i$, then complex conjugation $\sigma$ amounts to the permutation $(12)(34)$. But if we relabel them $\beta_1=i$, $\beta_2=\sqrt2i$, $\beta_3=-i$, $\beta_4=-\sqrt2i$, then we have $\sigma=(13)(24)$. Here the relabeling permutation is $\pi=(23)$, and $(12)(34)$ gets replaced with $\pi(12)(34)\pi^{-1}$. The same with the other automorphisms of $Gal(f)$.

Comment: (cont'd) For example, that Galois group also contains the automorphism $\delta$ defined by $i\mapsto -i$, $\sqrt2\mapsto -\sqrt2$. In the $\alpha$-labelling $\delta=(12)$, and in the $\beta$-labelling $\delta=(13)$. Again $\pi(12)\pi^{-1}=(13)$. The relabelling of the roots conjugates all the permutations by the relabelling permutation.

Comment: For your second comment I suppose the $\pi=(123)$. And what you wrote makes sense to me. But to show this in general I need to show that there always exist such $\pi$. But how can I be sure of that?

Comment: Ah, I suppose it is something like, that there always exist a permutation which will relabel the roots. In this way we'll more think of it as: given a $\pi$ (relabeling) we can translate our original labeling $\tau_1$ the to new labeling $\tau_2$ s.t. $\pi \tau_1 \pi^{-1} =\tau_2$.

Comment: Or, idk. Maybe I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of this question is to be found in:

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/conjclass.pdf

(another paper from Keith Conrad)

More precisely, it follows straight from thr 5.1. in the paper.